# After increasing the node memory limit up to 16gb. I am facing memory heap size issue in Node Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

After increasing the node memory limit up to 16gb. I am facing memory heap size issue in Node Javascript
Case
Previously I was not facing issues on development mode, with babel-node. But I removed babel-node due because of the custom webpack config now I am facing the issue.

Comment: Which version of Nodejs are you using?

Comment: Issue was solved,  I was using node js 14. But the issue was due to source-map (devtool property in webpack) at server side node js build. So we removed it. 
Using 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' instead 'cheap-source-map' also help but we have to comment some  webpack entry code .